# Merging Urban Paths and ITN data in a network

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, multimodal-network, network-dataset, arcgis-10.5

I have an ITN network created within ArcMap. I also have urban paths data for the same area. I would like to merge both datasets into one network. I would like the network to be multimodal. I cannot figure out how to do this. I have tried using productivity suite, but I cannot create a network using both Urban Paths and ITN simultaneously.

Comment: this might be related https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/forums/discussion/1001608/urban-paths-itn-layer-difficulties/ The prefix must be the same.